# How do I move the start position of a range until a double quotation mark is reached

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, office-addins, word-addins

I want to move the start position of a `Range` object until it meets the first double quotation mark. I used this code but it is not moving to meet the mark:

```
object cSet = "\"";
Range range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
range.MoveStartUntil(cSet);
```

If I use a different character, however, it moves to meet the character. I believe the reason for this behavior has to do with the dedicated function of `"` for declaring string literals. Is it possible to use the double quotes as part of a character set to move the range start or end position to?

Comment: If you are searching in Word then it is more than likely that the quotes will be smart quotes. ' “ ' or ' ” ' rather than a standard double quote ' " '.  If you are looking for the opening smart quote then you will need to use cSet = Chr(147).  The closing smartquote is Chr(148).

Comment: @freeflow, thanks for the hint. I have finally figured it out. I am actually using c# not VB. So what I used is `char c = (char) [code] ` casting the code to a `char` object and then generating the character set from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution using the hint provided by @freeflow in the comments.

The quotes in the word document is the smart curly quotes which is different from the straight quotes `"` used in the string. So I had to get the character code representation of smart curly quotes by getting the the quotes from the document and casting it to int thus:

`Range range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range 
int code = (int)range.Text`

This returned 8220 and 8221 for the opening and closing smart quotes respectively.

The required character set then becomes:

`object cSet = "\"" + (char)8220 +(char)8221;`

The straight quote is still included in the cSet in case the Add in encounters it in the document in which smart quotes have been converted to straight quotes.